# AHK WorkSheetFunction.Day

Tags: autohotkey, worksheet-function

Could anyone help me out with this issue please?
I don’t know what is wrong with my code `D:= XL.Application.WorksheetFunction.Day(XL.Range(“A11”).value)`
Above code i am trying to get day from a date in range A11 where its value is 26-Nov-2020.

Thank you very much

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place. Also, please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I am trying to use WorkSheetFunction but it doesn’t work. My above code, i googled it but no idea why it does not work. My script got error on that line. It says “unknown”

Comment: I tried vlookup and it worked but why not day?